# Auto Installer for Cake PHP Application

Tags: deployment, installation, cakephp-1.3

I am developing a Cake PHP application. I am wondering if there is a simple way to create auto installer for the Cake PHP application (similar to one available for most of the commercial and open source CMS e.g. Joomla, WordPress).

I guess below are the steps involved.

- Check if the target system meets Cake PHP requirements ( along with extra libs if any)
- Take DB credentials as input and run sql file to create the schema
- Delete and temp files created in the process along with installer files (to save user from accidentally overwriting the DB and files)

It would be great if someone can help me out with step by step process for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help - http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2007/04/16/writing-an-installer-for-your-cakephp-application/